# What is the syntax for Function.prototype.call or Function.prototype.apply with an async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

What is the syntax for using the `call()` or `apply()` methods to change `this` when dealing `async` functions?

So by way of example:

```
class Foo {
    async someLongMethod(){
        ... Do stuff
    }
}

class Bar {
    async someOtherMethodThatWillWait(){
        //Will the following work?
        await Foo.prototype.someLongMethod.call(this);
        ... Do stuff but only after someLongMethod has completed

    }
}
```

Comment: `Will the following work` Why not just try it? It looks OK to me

Comment: `await` acts on promises, so as that method returns a promise you're fine. It's certainly syntactically valid.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Since it's an `async` function, it will necessarily return a `Promise`

Comment: @CertainPerformance ah, hadn't spotted that it was also in the example, thanks!

Comment: @CertainPerformance protractor via node accepts the syntax I just wanted to make sure the method was indeed behaving in a synchronous manner via the await command. It makes senses that if all an await command requires is a function that returns a promise then it should work. I just wasn't sure. Thanks I'll see if I can setup a dummy test to see if the code is 'awaiting' so to speak.

Comment: No, Promises in any form are *not* synchronous (except when calling the constructor, initially)

Comment: @CertainPerformance totally agree Promises are asynchronous. I was not saying they weren't. In fact the method I was referring to as behaving synchronously was the 'someOtherMethodThatWillWait'. I wanted to make sure the syntax of the invocation the async method 'someLongMethod' was correct so that the async / await pattern would be respected. The synchronicity that I was referring to was with regards the async / await pattern and not promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same as the syntax for calling normal functions, there is no difference. You cannot really distinguish an `async function` from any other `function` that returns a promise.

Comment: I managed to test the call within protractor through node using a browser wait and it does indeed work. Thanks for everyone's input.